# How to get an instance of the registered view in ContentRegistered?

Tags: c#, mvvm, c#-4.0, prism, prism-4

I have the following code in one of my Modules :

> public class MyModule : IModule
>       {
>           private IRegionManager mRegionManager { get; set; }
>
> ```
>     public MyModule (IRegionManager regMan)
>     {
>         mRegionManager = regMan;
>
>         IRegionViewRegistry ir = 
>                 ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionViewRegistry>();
>         ir.ContentRegistered += new
>                 EventHandler<ViewRegisteredEventArgs>(ir_ContentRegistered);
>     }
>
>     void ir_ContentRegistered(object sender,ViewRegisteredEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // How get an instance of BaseTableView
>     }
>
>     public void Initialize()
>     {
>         mRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion",typeof(BaseTableView));
>     }
> }
> ```

How can i have an instance of BaseTableView in the ir_ContentRegistered event handler?

Comment: Do you want to use ViewRegisteredEventArgs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e.GetView()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.viewregisteredeventargs.getview(v=pandp.38).aspx

Note that `GetView` is a property, that returns a `Func<Object>`, which is then invoked: `()`.

Comment: Then how am i suppose to reach the BaseTableView?

Comment: `(BaseTableView)e.GetView()`;